# popup window.open on any url address

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, popup, window.open

i am using JSF 2.1 , primefaces , javascript.

i want to use **window.open** function on any url of application. for example if client copy URL of MyApp (e.g **locahost/MyApp/home.xhtml** OR **locahost/MyApp/logedin.xhtml** etc(any url)) and paste this on address bar of browser when client hit GO button then browser should open that URL in **window.open()** you can say that i dont want to use browser default tab for my application.
i have searched this but did not find any solution.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What exactly is not functioning?

Comment: @ŁukaszLech basically i have index.xhtml file which execute on when client requests this URL **localhost:8080/MyApp/** there is a one button `Click<h:commandLink value="here" onclick="fullwin('xhtmls/login.xhtml')" />` which executes fullwin() function on click `function fullwin(targeturl){
window.open(targeturl,"","status=no,toolbar=no,titlebar=no, location=no, top=0, left=0, width="+screen.width+", height="+screen.height+",scrollbars=yes,fullscreen=yes,channelmode=yes"); }` after that a new window popup but if client requests this **localhost:8080/MyApp/anyurl** this will not open any popup

Comment: @ŁukaszLech i want to open popup on when client requests any URL in browser address bar if popup already opened then get focus on opened one, if closed open new one